# Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: xubuntu, dependencies, qt

First of all I would like to say that I'm not an experienced Linux user, so please, don't be too '*techy*' with me.
I'm trying to install **XnViewMP** package on Xubuntu 20.04, but I'm getting this error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was googling and searching for a solution, but didn't find one. The only thing I understood is that I have some missing libraries the application relies upon? I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826862/qt5-1-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb/19913885#19913885) solution, `sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb1` and few other solutions I found on various websites, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: How are you trying to install the `XnViewMP` package?

Comment: I downloaded '.deb' package file and installed it with sudo apt install. After several unsuccessful attempts to install required packages I tried to uninstall all the packages I installed with 'apt remove --purge' and accidentally uninstalled critical packages, lol. I'm now reinstallng Xubuntu on my machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing missing packages. Those are the steps I performed:

1. I set the **QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS** to 1 with `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` command and ran **xnview** from the same command line. It returned the following output:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/XnView/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-icccm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-icccm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

2. I checked for missing packages with `ldd /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqxcb.so  | grep "not found"`

```
ldd /opt/XnView/lib/platforms/libqxcb.so  | grep "not found"
    libxcb-icccm.so.4 => not found
    libxcb-image.so.0 => not found
    libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => not found
    libxcb-render-util.so.0 => not found
    libxcb-xkb.so.1 => not found
    libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => not found
    libxcb-icccm.so.4 => not found
    libxcb-image.so.0 => not found
    libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => not found
    libxcb-render-util.so.0 => not found
    libxcb-xkb.so.1 => not found
    libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => not found
    libicui18n.so.56 => not found
    libicuuc.so.56 => not found
    libicudata.so.56 => not found
```

3. I installed the missing packages.

```
sudo apt install libxcb-image0
sudo apt install libxcb-keysyms1
sudo apt install libxcb-render-util0
sudo apt install libxcb-xkb1
sudo apt install libxkbcommon-x11-0
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Fixed the same problem for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: my man!! thank you very much for this very detailed, very easy to understand fix! worked perfectly for me in ubuntu 18.04 even though it was for a totally different software

Comment: Fixed using this solution same issues on 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue trying to run wireshark.  I fixed with `xhost +`.  I'm not sure why I needed that now, but it was failing to open the wireshark display.